# Concrete Sealer- Best color choice for a most natural color?

Tags: concrete, driveway, sealer

Long story short, I decided to apply some concrete sealant to my driveway in an effort to not have to do as much maintenance to it (Crack repair, pressure washing, etc). My HOA is complaining, as the color wasn't quite what I thought it would be, and is somewhat noticeable. They have asked me to reseal it with a color that is as close as possible to the natural looking concrete, to the point that it won't be easily noticeable. I'm at a bit of a loss how to achieve this, however.

What I used originally was "Valspar Concrete Gray" concrete sealer, https://www.lowes.com/pd/Valspar-Concrete-Gray-Solid-Concrete-Stain-and-Sealer-Gallon/5001893915 / Any ideas of what I can do to get the final sealer look to be closer to a natural look?

Comment: Concrete sealer comes in clear, apparently.

Comment: Get 50.01% of the HOA members to insist that everyone must use the same sealant you used, problem solved! Or, a new color each year!

Comment: The problem is, I already started non-clear, so I'm trying to fix this post. And yeah, I recognize now my folly, just trying to make the best I can of a bad situation...

Comment: Concrete doesn't have a single colour - it depends on what was in the mix.

Comment: I wonder if I can get them to match the sealer based on a sample of the concrete then? Hmmm...